# JavaScript - Reduce Array of Objects by Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Working with an array of objects like:

```
const arr = [
  {name: "qewregf dqewafs", value: "qewregf dqewafs answer", count: 2},
  {name: "survey with select", value: "survey with select answer", count: 2},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Donald", count: 1},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Jim", count: 1}
];
```

I am trying to reduce the array on matching values for the `name` key and achieve an desired output like:

```
desiredOutput = [
  {name: "qewregf dqewafs", data: [{value: "qewregf dqewafs answer", count: 2}]},
  {name: "survey with select", data: [{value: "survey with select answer", count: 2}]},
  {name: "werasd", data: [{value: "Donald", count: 1}, {value: "Jim", count: 1}]}
]
```

This attempt reduces the array, but I am missing how to merge the nested values without overwriting.

```js
const arr = [{"name":"qewregf dqewafs","value":"qewregf dqewafs answer","count":2},{"name":"survey with select","value":"survey with select answer","count":2},{"name":"werasd","value":"Donald","count":1},{"name":"werasd","value":"Jim","count":1}];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, d) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a.name === d.name);
  const value = { name: d.name, val: d.value };
  if (found) {
    acc.push(...value);
  }
  else {
    acc.push({ name: d.name, data: [{ value: d.value }, { count: d.count }] });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code actually throws an error because of the `acc.push(...value);`. It should be just `acc.push(value);`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You codes are a little close to the goal, just need to adjust something.

Please see the comment in below demo:

1. When `acc.find` doesn't find anything, then push one element `{name:d.name, data: [value]}`
2. if found, then push one `{value: ...}` into data property.

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "qewregf dqewafs", value: "qewregf dqewafs answer", count: 2},
  {name: "survey with select", value: "survey with select answer", count: 2},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Donald", count: 1},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Jim", count: 1}
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, d) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a.name === d.name);
  //const value = { name: d.name, val: d.value };
  const value = { value: d.value, count: d.count }; // the element in data property
  if (!found) {
    //acc.push(...value);
    acc.push({name:d.name, data: [value]}) // not found, so need to add data property
  }
  else {
    //acc.push({ name: d.name, data: [{ value: d.value }, { count: d.count }] });
    found.data.push(value) // if found, that means data property exists, so just push new element to found.data.
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not far off.  This would be a simple change to two lines of your code to achieve it:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "qewregf dqewafs", value: "qewregf dqewafs answer", count: 2},
  {name: "survey with select", value: "survey with select answer", count: 2},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Donald", count: 1},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Jim", count: 1}
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, d) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a.name === d.name);
  const value = { name: d.name, val: d.value };
  if (found) {
    found.data.push(value);
  }
  else {
    acc.push({ name: d.name, data: [{ value: d.value, count: d.count }] });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Here are the differences:

```
-     acc.push(...value);
+     found.data.push(value);


-    acc.push({ name: d.name, data: [{ value: d.value }, { count: d.count }] });
+    acc.push({ name: d.name, data: [{ value: d.value, count: d.count }] });
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a map with name as key and use `Object destructing` and `Object.values()` to get the desired result.

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "qewregf dqewafs", value: "qewregf dqewafs answer", count: 2},
  {name: "survey with select", value: "survey with select answer", count: 2},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Donald", count: 1},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Jim", count: 1}
];

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,{name, ...props})=>{
  if(!a[name])
     a[name]  = Object.assign({}, {name,data : [props]});
   else
    a[name].data.push(props);
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the use of the found object by checking if it does not exist and push a new object to the result set.

Then push an object with `value` and `count` to `data`.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: "qewregf dqewafs", value: "qewregf dqewafs answer", count: 2 }, { name: "survey with select", value: "survey with select answer", count: 2 }, { name: "werasd", value: "Donald", count: 1 }, { name: "werasd", value: "Jim", count: 1 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { name, value, count }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => name === o.name);
        if (!temp) {
            r.push(temp = { name, data: [] });
        }
        temp.data.push({ value, count });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "qewregf dqewafs", value: "qewregf dqewafs answer", count: 2},
  {name: "survey with select", value: "survey with select answer", count: 2},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Donald", count: 1},
  {name: "werasd", value: "Jim", count: 1}
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, d) => {
  let idx = acc.findIndex(a => a.name === d.name);
  let val = { value: d.value, count: d.count };

  if (idx > -1) {
    acc[idx].data.push(val);
  } else {
    acc.push({ name: d.name, data: [val] });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

You have to find the index first, and then push your data into that row.  You're just finding it but then pushing a new value to the array.