# How to generate table with dynamic header and body in angular 7 8?

Tags: angular

```
attribute | member1 | member 2
--------------------------------
Height    | 5ft     | 4ft
Weight    | 60kg    | 50kg

Data would be coming in array like:

header:[{name: member1}, {name: member2}]
body:[{attr: Height, attrVal:5ft, name:mem1},
{attr: Height, attrVal:4ft, name:mem2},
{attr: Weight, attrVal:60kg, name:mem1},
{attr: Weight, attrVal:50kg, name:mem2}]
```

and we need to show the data according to first column and header value.

Comment: header:[{name: mem1}, {name: mem2}]
body:[{attr: Height, attrVal:5ft, name:mem1},
{attr: Height, attrVal:4ft, name:mem2},
{attr: Weight, attrVal:60kg, name:mem1},
{attr: Weight, attrVal:50kg, name:mem2}]                  Data should be shown against the same member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to write some logic([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935632/2622292)) to group the height and weight attributes. This would do that for you:

```
tableData = {
  header: [{
    name: "member1"
  }, {
    name: "member2"
  }],
  body: [{
      attr: "Height",
      attrVal: "5ft",
      name: "mem1"
    },
    {
      attr: "Height",
      attrVal: "4ft",
      name: "mem2"
    },
    {
      attr: "Weight",
      attrVal: "60kg",
      name: "mem1"
    },
    {
      attr: "Weight",
      attrVal: "50kg",
      name: "mem2"
    }
  ]
};

tableBodyCleaned = this.tableData.body.reduce((acc, d) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a.attr === d.attr);
  const value = {
    name: d.name,
    value: d.attrVal
  };
  if (!found) {
    acc.push({
      attr: d.attr,
      data: [value]
    });
  } else {
    const index = acc.findIndex(item => item.attr === d.attr);
    acc[index].data.push(value);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

And then in the template:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Attribute</th>
    <th *ngFor="let header of tableData.header">
      {{ header.name }}
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let body of tableBodyCleaned">
      <td>
        {{ body.attr }}
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let attr of body.data">
        {{ attr.value }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-with-complex-structure?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Data is not showing according to member. If I change name from mem1 to mem2 still the data is not changing

Comment: Thanks @SiddAjmera  I modified html code and used ts logic and it is working for me.